# Add day to InfluxDB query select clause

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Hello, people.

Is there a way to add days to an InfluxDB query, like we do in MySQL?

Something like this:

`SELECT time + 1d, last(field) AS point FROM measurement`

We can use time literals in the WHERE clause, but can we use them on the SELECT one?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible, as far as I know. Math operations also not supported on `time`. If you are doing something with timezones perhaps this could be helpful https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-time-zone-clause

Comment: No, not exactly, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this problem is to insert a separate (redundant) epoch seconds integer field into my measurement.

Comment: Yea, that might be the only temporary solution for now... thanks!